# Fan in/fan out concurrency with Monix

Tags: scala, monix

I'm trying to learn Scala and having a good bit of fun, but I'm running into this classic problem. It reminds me a lot of nested callback hell in the early days of NodeJS.

Here's my program in psuedocode:

1. A task to fetch a list of S3 Buckets.
2. After task one completes I want to batch the processing of buckets in groups of ten.
3. For each batch:
4. Get every bucket's region.
5. Filter out buckets that are not in the region.
6. List all the objects in each bucket.
7. println everything

At one point I wind up with the type: `Task[Iterator[Task[List[Bucket]]]]`

Essentially:

The outer task being the initial step to list all the S3 buckets, and then the inside Iterator/Task/List is trying to batch Tasks that return lists.

I would hope there's some way to remove/flatten the outer Task to get to `Iterator[Task[List[Bucket]]]`.

When I try to break down my processing into steps the deep nesting causes me to do many nested maps. Is this the right thing to do or is there a better way to handle this nesting?

Comment: The moment you have a **Iterator[Task[X]]** you can use `sequence` to turn it into a **Task[Iterator[X]]**. Even better, you probably end up in that situation because of a `iterator.map(f)` where `f` returned the task, you can do `iterator.traverse(f)` which will again give you the **Task[Iterator]**. Then you may keep `flatMapping` everything. PS: I would also suggest using some streaming solution, if you do not want to pull _fs2_ you can use the _obserbavles_ moulde of _monix_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, I would suggest something like FS2 with Monix as F:

```
import cats.implicits._
import monix.eval._, monix.execution._
import fs2._

// use your own types here
type BucketName = String
type BucketRegion = String
type S3Object = String

// use your own implementations as well
val fetchS3Buckets: Task[List[BucketName]] = Task(???)
val bucketRegion: BucketName => Task[BucketRegion] = _ => Task(???)
val listObject: BucketName => Task[List[S3Object]] = _ => Task(???)

Stream.evalSeq(fetchS3Buckets)
  .parEvalMap(10) { name =>
    // checking region, filtering and listing on batches of 10
    bucketRegion(name).flatMap {
      case "my-region" => listObject(name)
      case _           => Task.pure(List.empty)
    }
  }
  .foldMonoid // combines List[S3Object] together
  .compile.lastOrError // turns into Task with result
  .map(list => println(s"Result: $list"))
  .onErrorHandle { case error: Throwable => println(error) }
  .runToFuture // or however you handle it
```

FS2 underneath uses cats.effect.IO or Monix Task, or whatever you want as long is it provided Cats Effect type classes. It builds a nice, functional DSL to design streams of data, so you could use reactive streams without Akka Streams.

Here there is this little problem that we are printing all results at once, which might be a bad idea if there was more of them than the memory could handle - we could do the printing in batches (weren't sure if that is what you wanted or not) or make filtering and printing separate batches.

```
Stream.evalSeq(fetchS3Buckets)
  .parEvalMap(10) { name =>
    bucketRegion(name).map(name -> _)
  }
  .collect { case (name, "my-region") => name }
  .parEvalMap(10) { name =>
    listObject(name).map(list => println(s"Result: $list"))
  }
  .compile
  .drain
```

While none of that is impossible in bare Monix, FS2 makes such operations much easier to write and maintain, so you should be able to implement your flow much easier.

Comment: That was so much easier. I can't tell you how long I've been struggling with this and fs2 was a breeze! Thank you. Would love to know what your interest in Scala revolves around. What sort of things are you building?

Comment: Various things. At work things with Akka Streams and event buses, but i also pay attention to FS2 because I use Cats as often as Akka. Recently I did 2 small PoC with FS2: https://github.com/MateuszKubuszok/remote-sync-example and https://github.com/MateuszKubuszok/fpge - one is a recruitment task, and the other is a functional wrapper around game engine. I don't think anyone would use them, but they could be used as examples/demos of sort.